# GSheets JSON String Splitter, with Dynamic Column Selection, Dynamic JSON Strings

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script that I am using to split out a JSON string.
Currently the script is working for some but not for others, there is one edge case that breaks the script, this is in Row 2 and Highlighted RED 
I want the script to work for any JSON string, not have the dependency on the additional info tag
I have created a sample workbook here to highlight the JSON string breaking the splitter [Splitter Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BMiVuAgDbibLw6yUG3IZ9iw4MZTaVVegkw_k3ItQ4mU/edit#gid=586997970)

Any help here would be amazing!

```
function JSON_SPLITTER() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var inputsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var outputsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Current Output");

  // 0. 
  var response = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('JSON String Heading', 'Enter Column Heading for the JSON String in Row 1 Exactly as it appears', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
    var JSONcolumnname = response.getResponseText()

  // 1. Retrieve values from the input sheet.
  var [head, ...additionalinfo] = inputsheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Check "DATA" column.
  var dataIdx = head.indexOf(JSONcolumnname);
  if (dataIdx == -1) throw new Error("No DATA column.");

  // 3. Retrieve all keys from JSON data of the "DATA" column.
  var headers = [... new Set(additionalinfo.flatMap(r => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? Object.keys(obj.additionalInfo) : Object.keys(obj);
  }))];

  // 4. Create values of JSON data.
  var objValues = additionalinfo.map(r => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? headers.map(h => obj.additionalInfo[h] || "") : headers.map(h => obj[h] || "");
  });

  // 5. Create output values.
  additionalinfo.forEach((r, i) => r.splice(dataIdx, 1, ...objValues[i]));
  head.splice(dataIdx, 1, ...headers)
  var res = [head, ...additionalinfo];

  // 6. Put the values to the output sheet.
  outputsheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

Comment: I saw your sample Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. So, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your updated Spreadsheet, I understood that your expected input and output situations are `Sample Input 1` and `Expected Output 1` sheets, respectively. If my understanding is correct, for example, I cannot understand the logic for showing the value of `passportValidateDate` in the header row of `Expected Output 1` sheet. I cannot find this value in `Sample Input 1` sheet. How about this?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? I cannot still understand the logic for retrieving `passportValidateDate` in your sample input. So, if my proposed modification is not used, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
// 3. Retrieve all keys from JSON data of the "DATA" column.
var headers = [... new Set(additionalinfo.flatMap(r => {
  var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
  return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? Object.keys(obj.additionalInfo) : Object.keys(obj);
}))];

// 4. Create values of JSON data.
var objValues = additionalinfo.map(r => {
  var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
  return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? headers.map(h => obj.additionalInfo[h] || "") : headers.map(h => obj[h] || "");
});
```

#### To:

```
// 3. Retrieve all keys from JSON data of the "DATA" column.
var headers = [... new Set(additionalinfo.flatMap(r => {
  var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
  return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") && obj.additionalInfo ? Object.keys(obj.additionalInfo) : Object.keys(obj); // Modified
}))];

// 4. Create values of JSON data.
var objValues = additionalinfo.map(r => {
  var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
  return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") && obj.additionalInfo ? headers.map(h => obj.additionalInfo[h] || "") : headers.map(h => obj[h] || ""); // Modified
});
```

- When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, in your sample JSON data, I found that while the property of `additionalInfo` is existing, the value of `additionalInfo` is `null`. So I proposed the above modification.

#### Note:

- From your script, I guessed that the inputted value of the prompt is `DATA`.
- This modification uses your provided sample sheet of `Sample Input 1`. Please be careful about this.